# Как правильно изменить функцию wc_add_to_cart_message()?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу добавить атрибут продукта к сообщению корзины, которое появляется когда товар добавляется в корзину: «3 x Товар добавлен в вашу корзину».

В итоге это должно выглядеть так: «3 {pa_attribute} x Товар добавлен в вашу корзину».

Почему - то при добавлении фильтра к функции wc_add_to_cart_message(), или редактирование как в данном случае - [Customize add to cart message in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837991/customize-add-to-cart-message-in-woocommerce-3), вызывает ошибку.
Пробую добавить данный код, но на второй строке возникает ошибка:

```
global $product;
$ed = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_attribute' );
```

Comment: какая ошибка возникает?

Comment: @Алексей  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_attribute() on null

Comment: У вас global $product нету) Вы хоть ошибку прочитайте

Comment: @WPPunk по правде, какие только костыли я уже не пробовал. Всякие различные способы получения атрибута какие только нашел на просторах. Пробовал плагины и пробовал редактировать их вывод - ничего не завелось. Либо ошибки, либо пустой результат.

Comment: Вы же сами скинули пример, в нем через параметр $products передается id и количество товара. Берете id и через wc_get_product($product_id) получаете свой товар, а через него уже то что вам нужно.

Comment: Cейчас я код скину)

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут:

```
global $product;
$ed = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_attribute' );
```

У вас `$product` не инициализировн, при вызове функции с ним и вылетает ошибка.

Попробуйте сначала получить продукт:

```
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
```